# How to repeat row group header on each page in SSRS on group

Tags: ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I have a simple (I think) report with a dataset that is grouped by 1 field in the report that is set to page break on each instance.  The tablix is a list, with 1 row group header, 1 detail row and 3 footers; the footers contain subreports.  I'm trying to get the group header to repeat on every page.  I've set the static tablix member RepeatOnNewPage = True.  I think I've tried every iteration of KeepTogether/KeepWithGroup, and the current group is never repeated on the next page.  I have no idea what I could be missing.

Any other things you can think of for me to check?

Comment: Select the tablix, in the properties pane, check the RepeatColumnHeaders and RepeatRowHeaders settings. This is slightly confusing as the wording differs from the context menu when you right-click the tablix, one says repeat header rows and the other repeat row headers. If in doubt, switch both on and if it works turn one off to test.

Comment: Both were already checked.